# Javafx Exception in program Start Method

Tags: javafx

I am facing error while running my JavaFX code. I created this simple stage and it says exception in program start method and much more. I am using Scene Builder 11 with IntelliJ IDEA 11.0.7. Any help will be appreciated.

```java
package calculate;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("view.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("cal");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

This is the error I am facing. I tried everything that I know but I am not able to solve the issue.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=127.0.0.1:52135,suspend=y,server=n --add-modules javafx.base,javafx.graphics --add-reads javafx.base=ALL-UNNAMED --add-reads javafx.graphics=ALL-UNNAMED "-javaagent:C:\Users\MUZAMM~1\AppData\Local\Temp\captureAgent2jars\debugger-agent.jar" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "D:\javabook\CalculatorNew\out\production\CalculatorNew;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx-swt.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.controls.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.fxml.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.graphics.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.media.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.swing.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.web.jar;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar" -p "C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.base.jar;C:\Users\Muzammil Hussain\Documents\JAVA\lib\javafx.graphics.jar" calculate.Main
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52135', transport: 'socket'
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Sharing is only supported for boot loader classes because bootstrap classpath has been appended
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
    at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessError: class com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper (in unnamed module @0xdbd940d) cannot access class com.sun.javafx.util.Utils (in module javafx.graphics) because module javafx.graphics does not export com.sun.javafx.util to unnamed module @0xdbd940d
    at com.sun.javafx.fxml.FXMLLoaderHelper.<clinit>(FXMLLoaderHelper.java:38)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.<clinit>(FXMLLoader.java:2056)
    at calculate.Main.start(Main.java:13)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run$$$capture(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
    1 more
Exception running application calculate.Main
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:52135', transport: 'socket'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

What can be done to resolve the issue?

Comment: Modify your `--add-modules` argument to include `javafx.fxml`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you haven't added javafx.fxml to your VM Arguments. Use this:

```
--module-path "\path\to\javafx-sdk-14\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml
```

You could also add javafx.media if you plan on using it in the future.